# How to accurately read a 64 bit register value using a method that can only read 32 bits at a time?

Tags: arm, embedded, microcontroller, low-level-io

Came across this question during a past interview, but got no feedback.

Since its a register, would I need to disable interrupts before accessing the register inorder to prevent data corruption? Thought of using two buffers, 32 bit and 64 bit, and sending the 32 bit buffer into a read32() and shifting it over accordingly to the 64 bit buffer. Lets just assume this is little-endian architecture.

I wrote a quick sample code on repl.it (***Output does not match register value***)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void read32(uint64_t *reg, uint32_t *buffer){
  memcpy(buffer, reg, 4);
}

int main(void) {
  
  //register
  uint64_t reg = 0xAAAAAAAAFFFFFFFF;
  
  //buffers
  uint32_t buf_32 = 0;
  uint64_t buf_64 = 0;

  //read LSW
  read32(&reg, &buf_32);
  buf_64 |= buf_32; //add LSW

  //read MSW
  read32(&reg+4, &buf_32);
  buf_64 |= ((uint64_t)buf_32 << 32);
  
  printf("64 bit register value: 0x%lx\n", buf_64);
  return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
64 bit register value: 0x1ffffffff
```

Comment: I think you should have left out you sample code, because you have a question, and code that does not do what you expect.  The question of why that code does not work is a different question.  It is also not clear how that code answers the question.  It is usually best if you don't know to just ask the question without proposing your own solution, lest it simply become a discussion about your proposal and not an answer to the question.

Comment: what do you mean by the term register?  Can see how an interview question would ask that but your code is different.

Answer (score 5):

Disabling interrupts will not prevent an I/O register that may change independently of the code sequence from changing.

Often where data consistency is required between two hardware registers that are larger than the architecture width, the hardware data sheet or reference manual will advise on how to read the data - usually by specifying the order in which the registers must be read to work with hardware mechanisms that make that "safe".

In other cases the method might be dictated by the nature of the registers and their function/behaviour.  For example if you have two 32bit timer/counters, with the overflow of one triggering an increment of the other, to form a 64 bit counter, then clearly the high-order counter will only change when the low-order counter overflows.  In that case you can simply read the low, then the high and repeat if the low has since wrapped :

```
uint32_t low_word = 0, high_word = 0;

do
{
    low_word = *low_reg_addr ;
    high_word = *high_reg_addr ;

} while( *low_reg_addr > low_word ) ;  // If low has wrapped, re-read

uint64_t full_word = (uint64_t)high_word << 32 | low_word;
```

So if the low-order register not wrapped after the high-order register has been read, then the data must be consistent, and the loop exit.  If it has wrapped, the data *may not* be consistent, and must be re-read.

Comment: Thank you for the clear explanation.  Also, the do while condition, shouldn't it be low_word != *low_reg_addr?

Comment: This will fail if it's a cycle counter (or faster).   (you cannot read the same value twice, ever).   Its safe to read `low1`, `high`, `low2`, and and subtract 1 from `high` if `low2` < `low1`

Comment: @NullException Good spot; fixed.

Comment: @RussSchultz : Good point, however there is more to it than that. `high_word` may increment _after_ it has been read but before re-reading low, in which case it should _not_ be decremented.  Working on it - thanks for spotting the flaw.

Comment: @RussSchultz  Thanks - issue addressed.

Comment: I think the question is after you can not generically.  And then to ask more specifics about the registers.  Here, you have answered that for a timer counter registers, which is a common idiom for practical programming.  However, it could be a bit field or a random number generator (in which case you might not care about a mis-read).  If it was an address that changed randomly, the sample code would at least need something to make the compiler re-read.  In the randomly changing pointer/address case, both high/low could change; leading to *Is a stale value appropriate to work with?*

Comment: Another example is a FIFO register.  Where each read actually gets the next value.  If the 'register' is behaving like RAM, then things might be safe.  So if you don't understand how the register works, you can not write code.  I think this is what the interview question was after?

Comment: @artlessnoise All agreed, although I gave two examples not only the timer/counter scenario.  My point was as you say, you need to ask questions in the interview to clarify the requirements.  I imagine that is the point - ask a vague question and see if the candidate knows enough to second guess it.

Answer (score 1):

One mistake I see with your code is &reg+4 would increment the pointer to x + 32 bytes. This isn't what you want since it should be just x + 4 bytes. You might want to consider typecasting to uint32_t. ((uint32_t *)&reg + 1) should increment by 4 byte. However, you will have to change your read function accordingly too.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This should work...

```
void read32(uint32_t *reg, uint32_t *buffer){
  memcpy(buffer, reg, 4);
}

int main(void) {
  
  //register
  uint64_t reg = 0xAAAAAAAAFFFFFFFF;
  
  //buffers
  uint32_t buf_32 = 0;
  uint32_t buf1_32 = 0;
  uint64_t buf_64 = 0;

  uint64_t *ptr = &reg;
  read32((uint32_t *)ptr, &buf_32);
  printf("32 bit register value: 0x%lx\n", buf_32);
  read32((uint32_t *)ptr+1, &buf1_32);
  printf("32 bit register value: 0x%lx\n", buf1_32);
  
  buf_64 = ((uint64_t)buf1_32 << 32 )| buf_32;
  printf("64 bit register value: 0x%lx\n", buf_64);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This works ... sometimes, but it is totally unreliable. The register (like a timer) can overflow after you read the first 32 bits. Btw. Using memcpy is worse here, you can't know if it reads the data in single bytes or by a single 32 bit access.